# Create a Text File From a Form Server Side Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webforms, text-files, server-side

I am using Ruby on Rails and have a form that gets information from user input. I then want to take the user input and write it to a text file on the server side. I hope to save the file in somewhere such as /public/UserInput.txt.

Is there a way to use Ruby on Rails to do this? Or do I need a different language to do this such as PHP? In either case can anyone give me an example of how this is to be done?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
The code I am trying that is not giving me a text file is:

```
after_save :create_file 

def create_file 
parameter_file = File.new('C:\\parameter_file.txt', "w")   
parameter_file.puts(:parameter) 
end
```

Comment: Does your server have permissions to write to that directory? What happens when another user wants to save a file and you overwrite it? Why aren't you using the block form of `open`, or, more simply `File.write`, so the file is automatically closed? Failing to close the file handle will consume all available file handles on your machine eventually and crash your code.

Comment: Thanks it was a permissions thing, but :parameters doesn't give me the user input from the form

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This isn't really a rails specific problem. It can be tackled in plain ruby.

```
path = "/some/file/path.txt"
content = "data from the form"
File.open(path, "w+") do |f|
  f.write(content)
end
```

where `target` is where you want the file to go, and `content` is whatever data you're extracting from the form.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but how do I incorporate it into a site built with ruby on rails? would that code go in my views or model? I am confused on where to place it.

Comment: In your model, preferably. You don't want this kind of code in the view.